# Mysql root password not working after reset

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

I have tried to reset my root password multiple times after logging in with --skip-grant-tables, however, every time I restart mysql server and attempt to log-in with the password, it fails.  I did `flush privileges;` after setting the password.  Any suggestions for next step?

Using Debian 9, Mysql 15, Mariadb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer and I hope it will be useful to others.  Since the grant tables were skipped, resetting the password never actually reset the password.  I needed to `flush privileges;` after logging in to mysql with --skip-grant-tables.  Then reset the user password, flush privileges again, restart mysql server, and boom!, access granted.